File downloaded from FTP with Python ftplib is encoded incorrectly
I'm retrieving a file from a NAS via FTP in two ways:

with a .bat file where I have:
a) ftp -s:C:\TEMP\runTheDownload.txt (The script calls the code from the txt)
b) The .txt containing the following:
open some.address.eu
username
password
ascii

quote "site SBDataconn=ANOTHER.ADD.RESS.HERE
get 'THE.NAS.LOCATION.OF.THE.FILE' C:\TEMP\output.txt


I have a Python code with above inputs where I use ftplib and the following code:
with FTP(ftp_server) as ftp:
    ftp.login(ftp_user, ftp_password)
    print("Connected to FTP server.")

    # Set transfer mode to ASCII
    ftp.sendcmd("TYPE A")
    # print("Switched to ASCII mode.")

    # Execute the custom FTP command (quote)
    ftp.sendcmd('SITE SBDataconn=ANOTHER.ADD.RESS.HERE')
    print("Custom SITE command executed.")

    # Download the file
    with open(local_file, 'wb') as file_obj:
        # Write info to buffer
        ftp.retrbinary(
            f"RETR {remote_file}", file_obj.write)



When I look at the output.txt from the first approach it gives me perfectly fine data like 001, abc, 2013230..., the Python output however gives me encoded returns like:

\x7f\xf0\xf0\xf1\x7fk\x7f\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf1\xf0\xf2\xf4\xf9\x7fk\x7f\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\x7fk\x7fN\xf0\x7fk\x7f\xf0\xf4\x7fk\x7f\xf0\xf0\x7fk\x7f@@@@@@@@@@\x7fk\x7f\xd6\xd7\xc3\xe4\xe2\xc5\xd9@\x7fk\x7f\x81\xa4\xa3\x96\x94\x81\xa3\x89\xa2\x83\x88\x85@\xc5\x89\x95\xa2\xa3\xa4\x86\xa4\x95\x87@`@\xf1K\xf7K\xf2@@@@@@@@@

I'm wondering what I'm missing in my Python code to transform it nicely like it is being done with the .bat file.
I tried decoding it in different ways, but it never gave me back anything that looked remotely like the proper result. Best thing I got was with "ISO-8859-1" decoding which led to

\x7fððñ\x7fk\x7fððððñðòôù\x7fk\x7fððððððððð...

I'm grateful for any advice on why the .bat file worked differently or how to properly decode in Python.
Thanks a lot!

With ftp you are using text/ascii mode:
ascii

While with ftplib you are using binary mode:
ftp.retrbinary(...)

With most FTP servers the difference would be only in EOL conversion. But apparently your FTP server is special.
To use text/ascii mode in ftplib, use FTP.retrlines.
